# nodeJS Dates & Mongoose saving to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Schema with fields called startTime and endTime of type Date and Number. What I want to do is have the startTime be the current time, which I have working now, and then the endTime to be 1 hour later than the start time. Here's the code I have now, but I'm not able to figure out the solution. The endTime isn't being saved to the DB.

i.e

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
var testSchema = new Schema({
     startTime : {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
     endTime : {type: Number, required: false},
});
testSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
     var testDocument = this;
     testDocument.endTime = Number(testDocument.startTime.valueOf() + 3600000);
     next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next. After setting endTime call next();

```
testSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
         var testDocument = this;
         testDocument.endTime = new Date();
         testDocument.endTime.setHours(testDocument.created_at.getHours() + 1)
         next();
    })
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I am using next() in the actual code. Just forgot to upload here.

Comment: You are not using that update query, right? Use same code as I have posted in my answer. It will work only at the when you are creating record.

Comment: In current case You need not to use update query inside the 'save' pre hook

Comment: hi, so I tried to remove the query, but it doesn't save anything for example

I'm trying another solution such as TaskSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
 //update the dueDate field of the assignment
 var task = this;
 if (task.isNew) {
  console.log('here');
  console.log(task.created_at.valueOf());
  task.endTimeNumber = task.created_at.valueOf() + 3600000;
 }
 next();
});
 but it wont save endTimeNumber to the Database

Comment: Is it going inside the if condition. And better update the question with exact code that you are actually using.

Comment: I updated the post. The problem is that the endTime variable is not being stored in my database, why would this be the case?

Comment: Why are you using starTime. It should be startTime. Correct it if it is wrong in your code. Nd if it is correct then console endTime and check it have number type value in it.

Comment: hi that did not fix it, but for some reason the type of endTime is showing as an object. I converted it using testDocument.endTime = Number(testDocument.startTime.valueOf() + 3600000);